# 2004 Volvo S60 starting issue

Tags: engine, battery, starting, car, volvo

I am interested in buying a 2004 Volvo S60. The guy selling the car says:

"It won't start. When you try to start it. its as if the battery was bad, but it's not"

Does anyone know what that means? What could be the problem? He's selling it for $750 but am trying to get it for less than $500.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like he bought a new battery to try to fix the issue but it did not.

There may be other causes (like fuses, wiring, a non-genuine immobilizer) but the next logical assumption is that the starter and/or starter solenoid have failed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2006 Volvo S60 and on mine when it won't start it's because the solenoid wire bolt on the top tip of the starter has come loose I tighten it and it starts fine until it comes loose again I would start there first then go to other issues it could be this simple fix